# Entity Framework automatically not mapped properties in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using entity framework code-first, I have a property.

1. bool isItTrue {get;set;} // this will get mapped (create a column in the DB)

[NotMapped]
2.  bool isItTrue {get;set;} // this will NOT get mapped

3. bool isItTrue {get {return someIntProperty < 3;}} // this will not get mapped porque why?

Now, I realize that it's a calculated field.

So my question is whether there is a set of rules on what will and will not be mapped to the DB.

For example, 
A property will be mapped unless
1) annotated with notmapped OR
2) Fluent API ignored ---- modelBuilder.Entity() 
  .Ignore(p => p.isItTrue);
3) calculated field?  No set method?
4) others?

If question can be improved, please lmk.

Comment: NotMapped could be a code smell when it comes to entity models. We try to keep our entity models [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object). Use ViewModels for the added stuff. [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: EF will try to map any column not specifically modified with the NotMapped or Ignore methods. It doesn't matter what the getter/setter look like. However, note that it **needs** a public getter, a public setter and a parameterless constructor for this - otherwise it can't fill the DataSet from your BO objects, can't fill the BO object from the ResultSet, or can't create materialized values from the result, so it will ignore those.

Comment: I noticed private getters, setters, and constructors can be used as well. Also, note that with EF Core 1.1, there is also a possibility to map columns without a setter.